# SynchronizationLockException (Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.) when releasing a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking

When releasing a lock I am receiving a SynchronizationLockException.

Of course, first thing I did was the Google search on the problem. I found two main erroneous patterns:

1. Releasing a Mutex on the different thread than it was created.
2. Using a value type as a synchronization object for a Monitor. Or
   modifying the synchronization object between entring and exiting the
   Monitor.

The problem is that none of these patterns fits my case.

I have a very simple synchronization scenario:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _myLock = new object();

    internal void Func1()
    {
        lock (_myLock)
        {
            //Some code here
        }
    }

    internal void Func2()
    {
        lock (_myLock)
        {
            //Some code here
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_myLock)
        {
            //Some code here
        }  // Here is where I get an exception
    }
}
```

Eventually I receive `SynchronizationLockException` on the line of `Dispose()` where the lock is released.

My question is not "What is the problem with my code" or "What am I doing wrong". Basically, I would like to know how (and under which circumstances) this could possibly happen that .NET implementation of lock throws this exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Heap corruption due to unmanaged code is always a possibility.  There's nothing in your question that would suggest this is likely at all.

Comment: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at MyClass.Dispose()
   at CleanupForm.OnBtnRemoveClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
...   
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: The object "_myLock" should also be "static" so it is a single object available to all threads

Comment: If Dispose is necessary in your lock ATM, then I would refactor to narrow the lock or to broden the lock so that Dispose happen well inside the lock or well outside the lock, but not part of the locking 
Also consider Monitor.TryEnter, it will give you more control over the lock
BTW, "lock"is syntactical sugar for Monitor.Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once got the SynchronizationLockException in List instance when it has been resizing its underlying array to fit new elements. The List instance has been accessed from three different threads and there was one lock missing...

I'd say: Triple check if you're doing thread synchronization the right way.

Furthermore, implement the IDisposable pattern the right way (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx). Maybe finalizer is giving you a headache.